# Comparing a PHP date with MySQL Date type

Tags: php, mysql, date

A beginner's question. I need to find all the records in my database that are dated with yesterday's date. This column is a DATE type.

In php:

```
$yesterday =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date. ' - 1 day'));
```

This is producing '2013-04-11' as expected. But when I attempt

```
$gamesQuery = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM scores WHERE home_team = $teamId AND game_date = $yesterday");
```

I am getting no matches. There is definitely a record in my database with game_date = 2013-04-11.

(I found many similar SO questions but nothing basic enough to help).

Comment: Isn't `$con` supposed to be at the other end

Comment: Echo out your SQL and run it directly in the database. It's probably an issue with timestamps being included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 $gamesQuery = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM scores WHERE home_team = $teamId AND DATE(game_date) = '{$yesterday}'");
```

I have been using this for lot of mysql date related queries.

Comment: This did it for me. Can anyone explain what it does?

Answer (score 2):

Use this (only sql):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM scores 
 WHERE home_team = $teamId 
   AND DATE(game_date) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you `game_date` field is in datetime format it won't match because the values aren't identical. Use [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) to extract the date first and then do your comparison.

```
SELECT * FROM scores WHERE home_team = $teamId AND DATE(game_date) = $yesterday
```

Comment: The field is DATE format. Thanks though - I tried anyway to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the difference in how dates are used and stored in php vs mysql. Try http://www.richardlord.net/blog/dates-in-php-and-mysql

This will not only give you the answer but teach you the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to set the correct format as well:

```
$yesterday =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date. ' - 1 day'));
$gamesQuery = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM scores WHERE home_team = ".$teamId." AND date_format(game_date,'%Y-%m-%d') = ".$yesterday);
```